# Gulp 4 and Jekyll. Rebuild task starts but won't finish

Tags: gulp, jekyll

This is essentially an attempt to use this: https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync/blob/master/gulpfile.js with named functions. For whatever reason, the jekyllrebuild task will start but not finish. When I change a .html or .markdown the console outputs the following:

```
[11:06:10] Starting 'jekyllrebuild'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
```

Apart from that it works well, not sure why the rebuild task hangs. Any help greatly appreciated, gulpfile below. Thanks!

```
var browsersync = require('browser-sync');
var cp          = require('child_process');
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var gutil       = require('gulp-util');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

var paths = {
    html: {
        src: './app/**/*.html',
    },
    jekyll: {
        src: './app',
        dist: './_site',
    },
    markdown: {
        src: './app/**/*.markdown',
    },
    styles: {
        src: './app/_sass/**/*.scss',
        dist: './app/css',
    }
};

gulp.task(jekyllbuild);
gulp.task(jekyllrebuild, gulp.series(jekyllbuild));
gulp.task(serve);
gulp.task(styles);
gulp.task(watch);
gulp.task('default',
    gulp.series(
        styles,
        jekyllbuild,
        gulp.parallel(serve, watch))
);

function jekyllbuild(done) {
    browsersync.notify('building jekyll');
    return cp.spawn('jekyll.bat',  ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
}

function jekyllrebuild() {
    browsersync.reload();
};

function serve() {
    browsersync.init({
        server: paths.jekyll.dist,
        notify: true
    })
}

function styles() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jekyll.dist + '/css'))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dist))
}

function watch() {
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, styles);
    gulp.watch(paths.html.src, jekyllrebuild);
    gulp.watch(paths.markdown.src, jekyllrebuild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is nonsense:

```
gulp.task(jekyllrebuild, gulp.series(jekyllbuild));
```

You can't pass two functions to `gulp.task()`. Looking at the [gulp 3.x task that you linked](https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L24) you probably want the following in gulp 4.x:

```
gulp.task('jekyllrebuild', gulp.series(jekyllbuild, function(cb) {
  browsersync.reload();
  cb();
}));

function watch() {
  gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, styles);
  gulp.watch(paths.html.src, gulp.series('jekyllrebuild'));
  gulp.watch(paths.markdown.src, gulp.series('jekyllrebuild'));
}
```